# SQL Import Wizard - Error

Tags: sql-server

I have a CSV file that I'm trying to import into SQL Management Server Studio.

In Excel, the column giving me trouble looks like this:
[image]

Tasks > import data > Flat Source File > select file

[image]

I set the data type for this column to DT_NUMERIC, adjust the DataScale to 2 in order to get 2 decimal places, but when I click over to Preview, I see that it's clearly not recognizing the numbers appropriately:

[image]

The column mapping for this column is set to type = decimal; precision 18; scale 2.

Error message: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Amount" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Can someone identify where I'm going wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: I believe I figured it out... the CSV Amount column was formatted such that the numbers still contained commas separating at the thousands mark.  I adjusted XX,XXX.XX to XXXXX.XX it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out... the CSV Amount column was formatted such that the numbers still contained commas separating at the thousands mark. I adjusted XX,XXX.XX to XXXXX.XX it seems to have worked. –